# How to point one domain to other domain

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain, redirect, cname-record, iis-8.5

We have one site **www.abc.com** which is hosted on server A and a redirect has been set up on this server which redirect this site to **www.xyz.com/reports**.
**www.xyz.com** is our sitecore site and having one page **reports**. Is there any way if we can point **www.abc.com** to **www.xyz.com** If traffic start reaching at out sitecore server we will handle redirect part from sitecore server itself.

Actually right now if we want to set up any redirect for **www.abc.com** we have to reach out to server A team so we just wanna remove this dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following way

```
<rule name="Redirect url1" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^url1$" />
 <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?example.com1$" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/url2"
  appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

Comment: Basically we made DNS change for www.abc.com to point to www.xyz.com where Incapsula layer comes into picture so we have set-up redirect in Incapsula
Thank you!